# Problem with pandas_datareader (StooqDailyReader)

Tags: python, pandas-datareader

I got problem with importing stock prices of "PKN" from stooq.com(https://stooq.com/q/?s=pkn).

With importing ^SPX prices everything is working good with

```
from pandas_datareader.stooq import StooqDailyReader

a=StooqDailyReader("^SPX").read()
```

When I'm trying to do same with "PKN" I'm getting empty DataFrame.
How can I get data of various indexes with `pandas_datareader` from stooq.com?

Answer (score 1):

By default [`StooqDailyReader`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/blob/master/pandas_datareader/stooq.py#L42) uses `US` as country for non-index symbols when nothing else is specified:

```
    def _get_params(self, symbol, country="US"):
```

This leads to querying a symbol `PKN.US` which does not exist. If instead `PKN.PL` is supplied, data is returned properly:

```
a = StooqDailyReader("PKN.PL").read()
```